# React-Router-Dom scroll to component doesn't work correctly on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a one page App where clicking a button will scroll down the page to a certain component.

It works flawlessly on a desktop. Looking at the same application on mobile it simply routes to the component without the slick scrolling action. I am not using React-Native. Simply making a web App responsive.

here is the code

My App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const styles = appStyles();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className={styles.root}>
          <Particles />
          <ScrollHandler />
          <NavBar />
          <Menu />
          <AboutMe />
          <Projects />
          <Contact />
          <ScrollTop />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is what handles the scroll

I simply put the id onto a wrapper div in my component, and it scrolls down to that component.

Is this possible doing it this way when using a mobile device??

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const ScrollHandler = ({ location }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById(location.hash.replace("#", ""));

    setTimeout(() => {
      window.scrollTo({
        behavior: element ? "smooth" : "auto",
        top: element ? element.offsetTop : 0
      });
    }, 100);
  }, [location]);

  return null;
};

ScrollHandler.propTypes = {
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    hash: PropTypes.string
  }).isRequired
};

export default withRouter(ScrollHandler);
```